Is the devil's throne in the air or at the bottom of the seas?
Saint Paul in a letter to the Ephesians teaches that the devil operates from the air and is the source of all the tempting voices in our hearts.
Ephesians 2:2

in which you once walked, following the course of this world, following the prince of the power of the air, the spirit that is now at work in the sons of disobedience

Paul says the devil has his throne in the air from where he launches his temptations , but if we dig deeper into the Bible we see that the devil has his throne in the sea. The tale of Jesus' encounter with a command of demons called Legion shows us that their master lives in the seas. Jesus commands them into the swine and they lead the swine into the sea and drown them to the bottom of the sea where their master is apparently enthroned.
Mark 5:13

So he gave them permission. And the unclean spirits came out and entered the pigs; and the herd, numbering about two thousand, rushed down the steep bank into the sea and drowned in the sea.

The other instances are where we see satan's kingdom or the sea beast rising up out of the sea and this kingdom is given all authority and power by the dragon or satan. So where can we conclude his throne is stationed,  the air or the seas?
Isaiah 27:1 (ESV)

In that day the Lord with his hard and great and strong sword will
punish Leviathan the fleeing serpent, Leviathan the twisting serpent,
and he will slay the dragon that is in the sea.


Do you have a textual reference regarding a 'throne' in connection with the Entity called : Satan, Diabolos, Tempter, Drakon, Adikios, Poneros, Apollyon, Abadon ?

@NigelJ, the kingdom of darkness has a leader and he has a throne

@Nigel we have to fill some gaps for ourselves, God won't tell you everything, yu need to do your spiritual homework

. . . . . .  so, you are unable to provide an hermeneutic reference.

@NigelJ, a kingdom divided against itself will fall, Jesus himself refers to Satan's domain as a kingdom and if its a kingdom then do your homework , they have a king and a throne

A well worded question does not require the reader to do homework. NigelJ is asking valid questions. Your tone "come on Nigel you can do better than this" is not constructive. I'm sure that you intend to be respectful but it's not coming across that way.

@DavidD, me and NigelJ are used to having these religious arguments that are constructive and that are aimed at improving knowledge and wisdom. I apologize if it doesn't came out as intended

@NigelJ, God be with your brother, I appreciate your questions, they are tough and provoke me to source my claims. I apologize again brother.

@DongLi Thank you. Appreciated. It is necessary to maintain proper interactions on the website.

@NigelJ, Thanks and God bless you abundantly like Job.

Since Satan is a spiritual being, the seat of his power is not a physical location. The "power of the air" is clarified in verse 12

For our struggle is not with flesh and blood but with the
principalities, with the powers, with the world rulers of this present
darkness, with the evil spirits in the heavens.

Satan is called a prince because he is a chief. This is similar to the use of the term in the Book of Daniel, where an unnamed spiritual being speaks to the prophet about various battles:
chapter 10:13-21

The prince of the kingdom of Persia stood in my way for twenty-one
days, until finally Michael, one of the chief princes, came to help
me. I left him there with the prince of the kingdom of Persia, “Do you
know,” he asked, “why I have come to you? Soon I must fight the prince
of Persia again When I leave, the prince of Greece will come; but I
shall tell you what is written in the book of truth. No one supports
me against these except Michael, your prince.

Unlike the "princes" of Persia and Greece or Michael, the "prince" of Israel, Satan's realm is not limited to one nation or people. Since he is also called "the god of this world," (2 Corinthians 4:4) we may think of it as a worldwide dominion of evil.
Conclusion: Satan lives in the spiritual world, which is sometimes referred as the heavens, or "the air." This does not mean, of course, that he lives in the kingdom of heaven. In this case "the heavens" simply means the spiritual world. His realm is general, not limited to a particular location or nation.

Reconcile the term power to refer to a throne because it is said that Jesus is at the right hand of power in the Gospels,  Satan is the prince of the power, could power refer to a throne since the power to the left of Jesus is God's throne

"Throne" is not mentioned in this letter, but it does appear in Colossians 1:16 -
"For in him were created all things in heaven and on earth, the visible and the invisible, whether thrones or dominions or principalities or powers; all things were created through him and for him."  It does not seem to me that this is necessarily an actual item -spiritual or physical - but refers to a power or authority. E.G., most nations today have "seats" of power in the Capitols, but do not have an actual throne as such.  I think Satan's seat of power is in people's hearts.

Then why did the demons choose to sink to the bottom of the sea, there is a reason behind everything

What's the difference between a seat and a throne,  that is in response to your earlier comment?

+1 @Dong Li, the "sea" in prophecy usually refers to the people of the earth. Thus, ha satan and his demons hide in and among the people of the earth, using them as hostages. According to Revelation, the lake of fire was prepared for the devil and his angels. God loves humanity and has done everything possible without violating free will and justice to save people from destruction.

@Dieter, thanks for the upvote, I agree with your interpretation that the sea represents people as explained by the angel . Why did those demons drown with the swine into the bottom of the sea?

@Dong Li, it's been speculated that the demons were trying to force the man to commit suicide. He stopped at gashing himself. But when they entered the swine, they got the terror and death they desired from the swine. The demons themselves didn't drown.

@Dieter, thanks for the new hint. Those demons had terrorized the man and Jesus gave him freedom much like he gives new believes freedom from the power of sin.

@Dieter, thanks for editing to add the reference about the dragon


Paul says the devil has his throne in the air

No he doesn't.

we see that the devil has his throne in the sea

No we don't.
These aren't facts, they are simply something that you personally think might be true.
It's not reasonable to expect everyone else to accept them as true.
If you are going to make claims like those, you need to fully support them with convincing biblical evidence.
So, the answer to the original question, "Is the devil's throne in the air or at the bottom of the seas?", is a simple "no".

The power of the air, Jesus is sited is sited at the right hand of power , which is a throne. Power == Throne , check the verses that say the people shall see the son of man sited at the right hand of power which means the gwt

The texts quoted by the OP, viz, Eph 2:2, Mark 5:13, Isa 27:1, establish nothing about the location of the throne of the devil/Satan for the following reasons:

None of them even mentions a throne
Mark 5:13 and Isa 27:1 do not even mention or describe anything about the devil/Satan.  Admittedly, Mark 5:13 describes an activity of his minions but nothing about Satan or his throne, or its location.
In the case of Eph 2:2, the text states that the devil is, "the ruler of the authority of the air".  That is, the text describes the devil's dominion but not the location of his throne.  The throne is not mentioned nor described.
In the case of the prophecy of Isa 27, "Leviathan" is used as a metaphor/symbol of the nations that oppressed Israel.  It is a common technique used by Bible prophets such as:


a dragon representing Egypt, Eze 29:3
a lion representing Egypt, Eze 32:2
various beasts representing a succession of nations in Dan 7
an eagle representing Israel and what happened in Lebanon
etc

Indeed, the ONLY text that even mentions the throne of Satan (in obviously figurative language) is Rev 2:13 where it is described as being in Pergamum.
Indeed, Paul was capable of symbolic language in many places.  Here is one just a few verses further on in Ephesians:

Eph 2:6 - and He raised us up together and seated us together in the
heavenly [realms] in Christ Jesus,

This is clearly not literally true.  Let us read the Bible with the meaning intended.
